# Teste unitario para aplicação de filtros

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, processamento-de-imagens

Quero criar um teste unitario para o método:

```
public BufferedImage negativo(BufferedImage image) {

    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {               
            int rgb = image.getRGB(i, j);                                
            int r = 255 - (int)((rgb&0x00FF0000)>>>16);
            int g = 255 - (int)((rgb&0x0000FF00)>>>8);
            int b = 255 - (int) (rgb&0x000000FF);
            Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
            image.setRGB(i, j, color.getRGB());

            }

  }

    return image;

}
```

Alguem tem uma solução?

Comment: Alguma solução para qual problema? Não está mesmo claro. Sim, eu sei que vc quer fazer um teste unitário... mas vai testar o que?

Comment: se o filtro esta sendo aplicado na imagem que foi gerada.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro qual é a sua dúvida... Você não sabe como testar? Eu provavelmente escolheria algumas imagens pequenas de teste e comparia com valores esperados fixos (e.g., pixel a pixel). Dê uma olhada [nessa resposta do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11006394/664577).